# Select rows where sum of a column equals a fixed value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to get one (or all) possible combination of rows where sum of quantity column equals 20

here an example :

```
id quantity
1   11          
2   1           
3   4           
4   12          
5   19          
6   10          
7   3           
8   13          
9   16          
10  14
```

I want to have less rows, in this example:

```
5   19 

2   1
```

If it's impossible this one is acceptable too:

```
5   19 
9   16
```

Comment: By combination, you mean two rows or a combination of more than 2 rows, or both of them?

Comment: How 19 and 16 gives 20 in that logic?

Comment: @Aashishgaba I want to select a row (or rows) to handle a value like 20, also with less rows. If there was a row with 20, it returns it or 19 and 1 returns it or 19 16 that they can handle 20 returns they.

Comment: @Tpojka actually 19 and 16 are two less rows that can handle 20

Comment: What about the case where there are 3 rows that can make the sum 20,  (10,3,7) ?

Comment: Then requirement is not correct "get rows that give 20 (some value)". You have to alter question with correct requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can [cross join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) the table to it self!

```
  $value = DB::table('myTable as t1')->crossJoin('myTable as t2')
            ->select('t1.id as t1Id','t1.quantity as t1Quantity','t2.id as t2Id','t2.quantity as t2Quantity')
            ->whereRaw('t1.quantity+t2.quantity=20')->get();
```